# How Do I Send An Email WITHOUT An Ethernet or WiFi Shield

Tags: library

I can only find info relating to the wifi shield, but I want to send an email without the wifi shield. For now, I just plan on leaving my arduino plugged into a computer, so I just want to use the computer's network connection. Is there a library or something I can grab for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean plugged-in via USB, then no. There's nothing you can do on the Arduino that would let you use the computer's network connection directly.

You would need to have a program running on the computer which would communicate with the Arduino via serial. It would effectively act as an intermediary, sending the email on behalf of the Arduino.

Unfortunately, I suspect you'd have to write the program yourself. It's possible that something similar already exists, but at the very least you'd probably have to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks I found an example of your answer: http://www.instructables.com/id/Tweet-a-Pot-Twitter-Enabled-Coffee-Pot/?ALLSTEPS. This project uses Python as the intermediary.

Comment: SLIP or "Serial Line Internet Protocol" is an older idea not heard of as much these days, but should accomplish this goal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol